# How to construct a concrete isotopy from figure eight knot to its mirror image?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

We know that figure eight knot is amphicheiral. But how to show that in terms of Reidemeister moves?

Just several instructive hints will help a lot. I really have no idea..

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a lot answers on this online. Perhaps you were just looking for hints and not answers, but google is your friend!

Here is a solution: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/85/50/c7/8550c726602c5a80dca3a294345cfa64.jpg

Answer (score 0):

just take a diagram that is unchanged (up to a planar rotation) under the reversal of all crossings, as in http://katlas.org/wiki/File:Figure8knot-rose-limacon-curve.png\